# Using curl to post an array to the godaddy api

Tags: php, curl, post, request, godaddy-api

I am trying to post a bunch of domains to the godaddy api in order to get information about pricing and availability. However, whenever I try to use curl to execute this request, I am returned nothing. I double checked my key credentials and everything seems to be right on that end. I'm pretty confident the issue is in formatting the postfield, I just don't know how to do that... Thank you to whoever can help in advance!

```
$header = array(
  'Authorization: sso-key ...'
);


$wordsArray = ['hello.com', "cheese.com", "bytheway.com"];
$url = "https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/available?checkType=FAST";


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); //Can be post, put, delete, etc.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $wordsArray);

$result = curl_exec($ch);  
$dn = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($dn);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll make sure to keep them on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. Media type of sent data must be **`application/json`** (by default this is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), and your PHP app must accept `application/json` as well:

```php
$headers = array(
    "Authorization: sso-key --your-api-key--",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Accept: application/json"
);
```

2. Post fields must be specified as JSON. To achieve this, use the **[`json_encode`](https://php.net/json_encode)** function:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($wordsArray));
```

---

Full PHP code is:

```php
$headers = array(
    "Authorization: sso-key --your-api-key--",
    "Content-Type: application/json", // POST as JSON
    "Accept: application/json" // Accept response as JSON
);


$wordsArray = ["hello.com", "cheese.com", "bytheway.com"];
$url = "https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/available?checkType=FAST";


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($wordsArray));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$dn = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($dn);
```